# flowScope variable isn't accessible in jspx

Tags: spring, spring-webflow, jspx

I have cardQuestion.jspx

```
<html xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
  xmlns:form="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" contenteditable="inherit">
<jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
 <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />  

   <head>
     <title>SS</title>
   </head>
  <body>

<label>${wordingPractice.question}</label>

 </body>
</html>
```

I have flow declaration wording-flow.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
                      http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd">
<var name="wordingPractice" class="Practice.WordingPractice"/>    

<view-state id="wording">
   <transition on="next" to="setTranslationDirection"/>
   <transition on="cancel" to="endState"/>
</view-state>      

<action-state id="setTranslationDirection">
    <evaluate expression="wordingPractice.translationDirection = requestParameters.translationDirection"/>
   <transition to="setSaver"/>
</action-state>

<action-state id="setSaver">
    <evaluate expression="wordingPractice.saver = saverExtension"/>
   <transition to="nextCard"/>
</action-state>

<action-state id="nextCard">
   <evaluate expression="wordingPractice.nextCard()"/>
   <transition to="cardQuestion"/>
</action-state>

<view-state id="cardQuestion">
   <transition on="cancel" to="endState"/>
</view-state>

<end-state id="endState" />   
</flow>
```

In method nextCard - I init question variable.
But when I call it in jspx: ${wordingPractice.question}
it get me Null poinnter exception.
Also, when I debug I see that when I call nextCard - this is ObjectID1 ,
but when I call getQuestion - this is ObjectID2.

How to access flow variable in jspx?

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by  changing approach:

```
<view-state id="cardQuestion">
   <on-entry>
       <evaluate result="viewScope.questionValue" expression="wordingPractice.question"/>
   </on-entry>
   <transition on="cancel" to="endState"/>
</view-state>
```

and in jspx

```
<label>${questionValue}</label>
```

But if somebody knows how to use object in viewScope - welcome to answer!

when I try to do the same:

```
 <evaluate result="viewScope.wordingPractice" expression="wordingPractice"/>
```

I face the same issue with null pointer

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify model attribute with the flowscope variable holding the form fields for your view.

```
    <view-state id="wording" model="wordingPractice">
       <transition on="next" to="setTranslationDirection"/>
       <transition on="cancel" to="endState"/>
    </view-state>

    <view-state id="cardQuestion" model="wordingPractice">
       <transition on="cancel" to="endState"/>
    </view-state>
```